# Return a variable after cURL process complete

Tags: php, curl

I have written some script that resides on two different servers and connected by cURL. This is my first attempt at cURL and it's taken a day of reading and some trial and error to get to where I am now. The scripts are working on all points apart from needing to have the $valid variable passed back to ServerA when ServerB has completed so that I can use it to trigger a message stack error system on SiteA.

On serverA I have the following:

```
<?php
$domain = HTTP_SERVER;
$domain_name = substr($domain, 7);
$module_name = "SagePayServer";

//set POST variables
$url = 'localhost/zc151/validity_check.php';
$fields = array(
                    'dname' => urlencode($domain_name),
                    'mname' => urlencode($module_name)
            );

//url-ify the data for the POST
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

On serverB I have:

```
<?php
require('includes/application_top.php');
$domain = $_POST['dname'];
$module = $_POST['mname'];

$install_exists_query = "SELECT * FROM al_monitor WHERE module_name = '$module' AND domain_name = '$domain'";
$install_exists_result = $db->Execute($install_exists_query);

if ($install_exists_result->RecordCount() == 0) {
$valid = 0; 
}else{
// Calculate dates
$todays_date = strtotime("now");
$delta_eleven = strtotime("+11 months");
$delta_364 = strtotime("+1 year -1 day");
$delta_year = strtotime("+1 year");

//the values you have above are TIMESTAMPS (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC)
//if you want dates, you can convert as follows
$idate = date("d-m-Y", $todays_date);
$wdate= date("d-m-Y", $delta_eleven);
$fwdate = date("d-m-Y", $delta_364);
$edate = date("d-m-Y", $delta_year);
// -- --------------------------------------------------------

//WRITE TO THE DATABASE
$sql = "UPDATE al_monitor SET idate = '$idate' WHERE
        module_name = '$module' AND domain_name = '$domain'";
$db->Execute($sql);
$sql = "UPDATE al_monitor SET wdate = '$wdate' WHERE
        module_name = '$module' AND domain_name = '$domain'";
$db->Execute($sql);
$sql = "UPDATE al_monitor SET fwdate = '$fwdate' WHERE
        module_name = '$module' AND domain_name = '$domain'";
$db->Execute($sql);
$sql = "UPDATE al_monitor SET edate = '$edate' WHERE
        module_name = '$module' AND domain_name = '$domain'";
$db->Execute($sql);
// -- --------------------------------------------------------   
$valid=1;
}
// End insert module installation date into central database
```

How can I pass the variable back so that I can have an if/else statement in the script on SiteA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

> **CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER**: Set value to TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

Try:

```
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

`$result` should now contain the returned data from your CURL request.

---

You'll also need to output the `$value` in your script on Server B after you've finished processing things:

```
echo $value;
```

Comment: It would probably also be a good idea to use `json_encode` on server B, and `json_decode` on server A.

Comment: Another note, using `count($fields)` to represent true or false for your CURLOPT_POST option is probably not a good idea... Sure it will loosely evaluate to true when the array isn't empty, and loosely evaluate to false when it is, but I think you'd be better to pass true in by default and not perform the request at all if its empty...

Comment: @scrowler. Works perfectly. Thanks very much for the other advice too. As I said, today is the first time I've ever tried anything with cURL so it's been a steep learning curve.